# Assets Module Not Working

Tags: assets

My Assets plugin is not working on EE 2.4.  It continually loads.  Also when I try to add an asset when adding an entry, nothing comes up when I click "Add File".  [image: Asset Screen]  I have Super Admin access and when I click "Settings" I just get a blank field for "License Key"

Answer (score 1):

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at . (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

By default browsers won't let JavaScript requests that originate on one domain make a call to another domain, so they'll show that error you're receiving.

In the case of EE and Assets, that usually means you're accessing the EE control panel from a different domain that's specified in your `Admin->General Configuration->URL to your "themes" folder` and `URL to the root directory of your site` settings.

And keep in mind that `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` are technically considered two different domains. That often trips people up.

Comment: It worked when I added "www" to the URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This type of behavior is usually caused by a missing script asset. Open your browsers developer tools (F12 or Command+Alt+i) and look at the developer console or network tab to see if some files aren't loading. Also, you might see other errors in your console; perhaps you've recently added an accessory that is dumping extra scripts on the page that they are namespace collisions with something related to Assets.

Often, just re-uploading the third-party themes folder for an add-on resolves these issues.

Comment: This is the error:  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at <url>. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: ... is your themes URL pointing to a different domain?

Comment: Looks right, to the themes folder